# How can I animate a div off-screen without extending the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery/Javascript and am trying to animate a DIV off-screen.

The problem is after it animates to a `left: 125%` which is off-screen, the webpage just extends. This means the user could scroll to the right and see where it went.

How can I create a fixed page size or something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, changing the position of the animated element to `fixed` is a common workaround to stop the parent element(s) from being affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `overflow: hidden` in CSS:

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

You *may* need to revert it back after the animation is done, so as not to obstruct the contents scrolling.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is all I needed :)

Comment: As a side-note, you COULD put the animated div inside of a container that was width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden, so that you weren't hitting the whole body element with the overflow hidden.

Comment: @user3078911 Please note the above comment.

Comment: @user3078911 You there?